# getting the position of a string in a list using lisp

Tags: common-lisp

I have defined a list called `*words_list*`, whose content is  `("potato" "food" "bread")`.

I want to get the index of one of its elements, let's say "bread". 
For that I use

```
(setq  word_index (position   'bread   *words_list*))
```

I keep on getting `NIL` as a Return value..while element does exist in the list.
What am I missing?

Comment: `bread` is a symbol, `"bread"` is a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems.

First, the elements of your list are strings, but you're giving a symbol to `POSITION`. To correct that, you should write:

```
(setq word_index (position "bread" *words_list*))
```

But this won't work because the default comparison function used by `POSITION` is `EQL`. Every time you type a string literal, a new string is created, and they're not `EQL` to each other even if they have the same contents:

```
(eql "bread" "bread") => NIL
```

You need to specify the comparison function using the `:TEST` keyword argument.

```
(setq word_index (position "bread" *words_list* :test #'string=))
```

Use `string-equal` instead of `string=` if you want case-insensitive comparison.

Answer (score 1):

To get what you are looking for, you need `:test`:

```
(position 'bread *words_list* :test #'string-equal)
```

Note that `'bread` is a `symbol`, while `"bread"` is a `string`, so they are *not* `eql` (which is the default `:test` predicate).

Answer (score 1):

The symbol `bread` is not in your list.  You probably want

1. to understand the difference between symbols and strings;
2. to use something like `(position "bread" words-list :test #'string=)`.

(This is not meant as sarcasm: understanding strings and symbols is much harder than it once was due to languages which don't have symbols and where you are forced to use strings as a poor-person's substitute.)